# How do I create a hash from an array by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

I've an Array, `[name1-name1@email.com,name2-name2@email.com]`.

I want to create a new Hash from this Array. The result should be:

```
users: [
        {
           name: "name1",
           email: "name1@email.com"
        },
        {
           name: "name2",
           email:"name2@email.com
        }
       ]
```

Comment: Just so you know, the term for those things, what's Javascript's closest equivalent to Ruby's "hash", is "objects".

Comment: Just so you're aware. You're creating an Array of Objects from another Array. In JS there is no hash (not yet anyway).

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and objects for the result.

This solution features a `-` as the separator. This might not work for all emails, because `-` is an allowed character for emails. In this case, I suggest to use a different separator, like `|`.

```js
var data = ['name1-name1@email.com', 'name2-name2@email.com'],
    users = data.map(function (a) {
        var aa = a.split('-');
        return { name: aa[0], email: aa[1] };
    });

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume there are no other dashes in the email address?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, it might be just a random sign for separating the string. better would be a sign like `|` which is not part of an email address.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['name1-name1@email.com','name2-name2@email.com'];
arr = arr.map(node => {
    var ta = node.split('-');
    return {
        name : ta[0],
        email : ta[1]
    }
});

var users = {users : arr};
```

I do not know the difficulty ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ['name1-name1@email.com','name2-name2@email.com'];

var users = [];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
 var splitted = names[i].split('-');
 users.push({
   name: splitted[0],
   email: splitted[1]
 })
};

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`data = ['name1-name1@email.com', 'name2-name2@email.com']
 result = data.map{|s| {name: s.split('-')[0], email: s.split('-')[1]} }`